# Do Ubuntu Linux apps work on Kali Linux?

Tags: ubuntu, kali-linux

Do Ubuntu Linux apps work on Kali Linux?

I want to know if apps that can be installed on Ubuntu can also be installed on Kali.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since you are new to GNUL/Linux, I would suggest that you use another distribution than Kali Linux until you are, "not new":

> Kali is a Linux distribution specifically geared towards professional
> penetration testers and security specialists, and given its unique
> nature, it is NOT a recommended distribution if you’re unfamiliar with
> Linux

As for running Ubuntu apps in Kali, this is also documented here in the [Kali Linux documentation](http://docs.kali.org/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux):

> While Kali Linux is architected to be highly customizable, don’t
> expect to be able to add random unrelated packages and repositories
> that are “out of band” of the regular Kali software sources and have
> it Just Work. In particular, there is absolutely no support whatsoever
> for the apt-add-repository command, LaunchPad, or PPAs.

The answer to your question then is,
*- No, not without tinkering.*
Which leads back to point one. Kali Linux is a **bad choice** if you are new to Linux.

Comment: @Kay You are most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The kali linux distribution is based on [**debian testing**](http://docs.kali.org/policy/kali-linux-relationship-with-debian) , some of its packages are imported from debian **unstable** and **experimental** (Latest versions) , by installing some packages from Ubuntu 14.04 repository you will get a dependencies problem's and you can break your system.

You can install **some** kali linux tools on Ubuntu without problem. I suggest to use Ubuntu , it is the best linux distro for beginners.